# Run some tests before rpm install

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I want to ship a file test.py with rpm.
And I like to execute "python test.py" in %pre.

But file is not available as %install didn't execute.
Is there any way to these stuff?

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: It's a test, which checks about few python modules available in PYTHONPATH, few other things too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no way to execute a file from your RPM package during `%pre`.

The only possibility you might have would be to find where the current RPM is located on disk and manually extract your file out of it but I don't know if you can reliably (or easily) do that from within a `%pre` script.

That all being said this sort of testing in `%pre` is generally, I feel, a bad idea as there isn't anything useful you can do if the tests fail and bailing out is **evil**. And more generally these are the sorts of things that should probably be asserted by `Requires:` entries in the rpm spec file.